# How detect the two word of a string like “helpme”?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have a dictionary table (words) and another table with concatenated 2 words like "helpme", "helloword" "loveme"...

I want to transform this table to "help me", "hello word", "love me"

I run this sequence :

```
SELECT 
  table_concatened.twowords,
  t1.word as 'word1',
  t2.word as 'word2'
FROM
 table_concatened
  JOIN dictionary_table AS t1 ON SUBSTRING(table_concatened.twowords,1,len(t1.word)) = t1.word 
  JOIN dictionary_table AS t2 ON SUBSTRING(table_concatened.twowords,len(t1.word)+1,len(table_concatened.twowords)) = t2.word;
```

It is working, but is took a very long time with my table.

How can I optimise my sql sequence?

---- exemple of table ---
dictionary_table

```
 |hello|
 |word |
 |love |
 |me   |
```

exemple of table_concatened :

```
|helloword|
|loveyou |
```

Edit: 
1) The use case is for autocorrection. For example on skype, on iPhone, on chrome, when I type "helloword", I have auto correction to "hello word".
2) The database here is not very important. Our issue is about algo logic and performance optimisation.

Comment: Why are you foolishly storing them combined as one string in the first place when you know you're going to need to separate them again later? This never ceases to amaze me. *I store my data the totally wrong way, and now I'm having problems using it. It's complicated/difficult/too slow/doesn't work right! Can someone help?* The answer is Yes - fix your data so it's stored properly to begin with, and all those problems using it go away. You don't have to optimize difficult things when they're not difficult in the first place.

Comment: And you cannot possibly be using SQL Server, PostgreSQL, and MySQL at the same time.  Add the tag for the **single** DBMS you're actually using, instead of just randomly adding things that sound familiar. Syntax and functionality is vastly different between those databases, and knowing the **specific one** you're using makes a difference in the answers you get. Please [edit] your post and remove the tags that **do not** apply. I know you get a suggestion when using the SQL tag that you should add a specific DBMS tag such as MySQL, SQL Server, etc., but that means the specific one being used.

Comment: Your query will necessarily be slow, because the `SUBSTRING()` tests can't be optimized with an index.

Comment: Note: I agree that you're better off formatting your table properly, but... As your query currently is, it can be simplified to `... t2 on t1.word + t2.word = table_concatened.twowords` rather than using substrings. Also, `substring(x, 1, ...)` is functionally the same as `left(x, ...)` but either way, you're not going to be able to use an index here.

Comment: Actually your query _could_ use indexes if it were this: `... from table_concatened c join dictionary_table d1 on c.twowords like d1.word + '%' join dictionary_table d2 on d1.word + d2.word = c.twowords`. But still, storing your data properly is a better idea.

Comment: @KenWhite mind if I copy your comment and paste it elsewhere?

Comment: @e4c5: Not at all. Thanks for asking first. :-)

Comment: I'm genuinely curious as to _why_ the data is held this way?  Surely you are really open to false matches?  Words like `tome`, `me`, `to` and `meme` as an example match `tomeme` in multiple ways.

Comment: Hi, the use case is for autocorrection. for example on skype, on iPhone, on chrome, when I type "helloword", I have auto correction to "hello word".

Comment: Some mistake are done by chrome to when I type "tomeme". But most of the time we only have 2 words "glue".

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind going dynamic (and if SQL Server)

```
-- Generate Some Sample Data
Declare @Dictionary_Table table (word varchar(50));Insert Into @Dictionary_Table values ('hello'),('word'),('love'),('me')
Declare @table_concatened table (ID int,twowords varchar(50));Insert Into @table_concatened values (1,'helloword'),(2,'loveyou')

-- Generate SQL and Execute
Declare @SQL varchar(max)=''
Select  @SQL = @SQL+concat(',(',ID,',''||',replace(twowords,'''',''''''),'||'')') From @table_concatened --Where ID=2
Select  @SQL = Replace(@SQL,MapFrom,MapTo) 
 From   (
         Select MapFrom = word
               ,MapTo   = '|'+ltrim(rtrim(word))+'|'
          From  @Dictionary_Table
          Union All
          Select '|',' '   -- Remove Any Remaining |
          Union All
          Select '  ',' '     -- Remove Any Remaining |
         ) A
Select  @SQL = 'Select ID,Value=ltrim(rtrim(Value)) From ('+Stuff(@SQL,1,1,'values')+') N(ID,Value)'
Exec(@SQL)
```

Returns

```
ID    Value
1     hello word  
2     love you
```

Comment: @nicolasbahout Happy to help.